# Is it possible to share vnc server's screen with its clients?

Tags: ubuntu, vnc

I am using tightvnc server and viewer on ubuntu 10.04 or above machines. I start a vncserver by using the command `vncserver :1` and vncviewer on the client machine. Now, my desktop is by default same for all vncviewers connected to the same server , i.e. any graphic activity on one client is reproduced on the other clients. This screen on the clients, is however different from that of my server. Is it possible that even the server shares its desktop with the clients ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard VNC servers create new sessions.  If you want to share the console session, you want to use something like the `vnc.so` plugin for x.org (`vnc4server` package) or [X11vnc](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/).